# Mediastore.Audio.Media get recetly added songs similar to native player

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-music-player

I am trying to get the last 20 songs which were added to my phone.

I tried this

```
  String[] proj = {"*"};
  Uri psUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

  String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
  String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED;
  Cursor psCursor = contentResolver.query(psUri, proj, selection, null, sortOrder);

  if(psCursor == null){
            return false;
  }
```

But this is returning songs be some other sorting. It is different from what my native music player is showing.

I also tried doing `DATE_MODIFIED` but that is also returning the same result.

How can I fix this

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + " ASC";
```

or

```
String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
```